# Excel2010 - Unmerge cells, transpose a column

Tags: excel-2010

I have a software that returns an Excel file with a list of candidates for a job application.  For this particular application, I get a file that has 259 candidates in it.  The Excel file produced returns seven columns.  Columns A-E contain single values (name, application complete, etc.).  Column F contains the job application questions and Column G contains the candidate answers to the questions. The information in Column A (Name), Column F (Questions) and G (Answers) are what I really care about.  My goal would be to unmerge the cells in columns A-E, put the information in Column F as a header, and rotate the answers in column G to be in a single row for each candidate.  Is there a way I can do this without having to transpose the answers for each candidate manually?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In H3 copied across to I3 and down to suit:

```
=OFFSET(G3,1,0)
```

Select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top.

Copy and paste one set of Questions somewhere safe.

Filter on ColumnF to select all but `AAAA` and delete those rows. Insert set of Questions with transposition (once only!).